# How to put the content of a Eclipse Project inside github?

Tags: github, egit

I have a Eclipse project and I shared it in github.

In my local repository I have: .../github/eer/content_of_project

So, in my github project [github project](https://github.com/marmundo/eer) I have eer/content_of_project.

I saw in differents projects that their contents doens't stay inside a folder. Ex:[reference](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR).

How can I do in my project using Egit to put my project contents inside the parent folder in github?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is when you share a project using Egit, you have to tick the box: Use or create a repository in parent folder of project.

After thar create a repository, because Egit doesn't recommend create a repository inside workspace.